# Can't add a "bin/console" command and run it in Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

In PhpStorm, under `Edit Configurations -> Run/Debug Configurations` I don't see an option to add a `bin/console` command, or can I use Shell Script if what is the correct syntax to add the command?

Comment: You are wrong. It's possible. Your `bin/console` is a plain PHP file. So use appropriate configuration type -- **PHP Script** (that executes PHP file in CLI mode)

Comment: For example: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000459124-Symfony-CLI-command-debugging-from-phpStorm-through-Docker-what-I-am-missing-here-

Comment: @LazyOne you're right it works.  So the one to choose is PHP script and add the path /bin/console thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **PHP Script** type of Run/Debug configuration in such case.

Your `bin/console` is a plain PHP file, so it should be treated as any other PHP script that is meant to be executed in a CLI mode.

So:

1. Create Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP Script" type
2. Point to your `bin/console` in "File" field
3. All other parameters (like command name and its arguments) go into "Arguments" field

[image]
*Image is for illustration purposes; taken from another [thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000459124-Symfony-CLI-command-debugging-from-phpStorm-through-Docker-what-I-am-missing-here-)*.